# Reputation graphs suggestion

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

I suggest reputation graph to be (re)introduced but I suggest two of them instead just one:

1. The one we used to have (reputation over time)
2. Daily/weekly/monthly reputation graph that would vary per day/week/month cumulative over time

Just having a list of per day reputation list isn't very helpful. A picture is worth a thousand words in this case.

Comment: @Robert - a list is *also* helpful but I miss the graph showing clearly the peaks and flatline moments.

Comment: @Wikis Commit At Area 51: I agree. I didn't say that list should go. I'm just saying that graphs should be there as well. A sort of list was there before as well.

Comment: @Robert - great, let's hope this idea gets momentum.

Comment: It's dead.  Look here: http://stackapps.com/

Comment: @Hans Passant: Look for what? Is there an app that does what many would like to have - various reputation graphs?

Comment: If you don't want to make your own (your profile suggests you can) then wait a couple of weeks and look again.

Comment: @Hans: You're a funny guy. I probably would if I had time. But I don't :)

Comment: Note: you can also you this greasemonkey script by balpha: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/98920: after installation, go to your reputation tab in your profile: a small "graph" link will be displayed at the top right corner of the reputation section. Clicking on it will display a reputation graph.